# Apply subtotals to each sheet except the active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to apply subtotals to each sheet in excel except the current or the active sheet according to following criteria:
Subtotals
At each change in 
Column 9
Sum
column 17 and column 18

I used the following code but it's giving me some weird error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet

For Each ws1 In Sheets
    If Not ws1 Is ActiveSheet Then
        Range("A1:V5").Select
        Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=9, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(17, 18), _
            Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
    End If
Next ws1

End Sub
```

Comment: It is helpful to let us know what kind of error you get.  All errors are weird in their own ways.

Comment: It says, "MS Excel cant determine which row in your list or selection contains columns labels, which are required for this command"

Comment: I have multiple sheets and I need subtotals on the respective sheet, When I clicked Ok on the error It gave me a subtotal of zero on my active sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is doing the Subtotal on the active sheet, because you never tell it to use `ws1` as the sheet on which to perform the task.

Try the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    For Each ws1 In Worksheets
        If Not ws1 Is ActiveSheet Then
            ws1.Range("A1:V5").Subtotal GroupBy:=9, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(17, 18), _
                Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
        End If
    Next ws1

End Sub
```

**Edit:**  To exclude several worksheets from being subtotalled, use something similar to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    For Each ws1 In Worksheets
        If ws1.Name <> "Control" And ws1.Name <> "AnotherSheet" Then
            ws1.Range("A1:V5").Subtotal GroupBy:=9, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(17, 18), _
                Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
        End If
    Next ws1

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the above but it's giving me a run time error'1004'. "This can't be applied to the selected range. Select a single cell in a range and try again". I have added a command button on my active sheet and the sheets that I want subtotals on starts from 3rd sheet

Comment: How should I exclude first two sheets. May be that's why the code didn't work because 2nd sheet contain some text data which is not to be subtotaled

Comment: I guess I have to do something like this to exclude first 2 sheets If ws1.Name <> "name1" Ad ws1.Name <> "Name2" Then   .......does it seems correct?

Comment: Change the `If Not ws1 Is ActiveSheet Then` test to be something that will exclude which sheets you want to exclude - e.g. `If ws1.Name <> "Control" And ws1.Name <> "AnotherSheet" Then`

Comment: @Navy - yep - exactly right (well, if you change `Ad` to `And` it is **exactly** right)

Comment: Thanks! That worked but I ran into another problem. I'll have to sort the data first on every each sheet and then apply the subtotals. I'll post the code for the sorting on each page. Please let me know what am I doing wrong there.